# Angular material 2 mat-ripple effect on mat-table cell when cell changes

Tags: angular, angular-material2

Is it possible to invoke the mat-ripple effect on a cell in a mat-table row when its content changes? The documentation on the mat-ripple subject didn't help me at all.

Comment: Ripple is meant to confirm a user interaction. I'm not sure it's the best solution for data that changes by itself if that's what you mean? https://material.io/guidelines/motion/material-motion.html

Comment: Is there a way then to programatically invoke the ripple on a cell of a row?

Comment: I am running a timer function that changes the  values of an underlying datasource to a table every 5 seconds. The table is active and I want to signal to the user that a change has happened to a certain row.